# Why am I receiving additional elements through channel?

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I've bumped in to a peculiar problem which I unfortunately haven't been able to reproduce in a minimal working example. I'll try to explain it and hopefully you can give me some hint at least.

I have two protocols: *A* & *B*. For each protocol there is one central party *p1*, and three outer parties, lets call those *pn*. Each party is implemented as a separate goroutine.

Protocol *A* is as follows:

1. All parties perform a calculation, separately, and send their result of type `*big.Int` to *p1*.
2. *p1* receives all results and puts them in a slice which it sends back to each party *pn*.
3. All parties receive the slice and perform a new calculation based on it, and send their result of type `*DecryptionShare` to *p1*.
4. *p1* receives all data and calculates a result.
5. All parties output a result `*big.Int`.

To help with this I have three channels, one that is used for sending data *p1* -> *pn*, one for *pn* -> *p1* and one to output final results back to main thread (e.i. all *pn* read from and write to the same channels). The result 1. and 3. from *pn* is of different types though so that channel type is `interface{}`.

Protocol *B* first initiates protocol *A* and then perform further calculations, which are irrelevant.

Here's to my problem:

Protocol *A* on it's own works without ever showing problems.
But, when I call *B* ~10 % of the runs, it panics in *A*, even though the only thing differing is *B* passing on the input parameters to *A*.

The error showing is

```
panic: interface conversion: interface {} is *big.Int, not *DecryptionShare
```

implying that *p1* receives a `*big.Int` while it is at step 4, although it already received every parties `*big.Int` in step 2.

I have tried staying at step 2 a while longer using `time.Sleep` and `select` but I never get an additional `*big.Int` at that step, it only occasionally shows up at step 4.

If I instead of `chan interface{}` use two seperate channels `chan *big.Int` and `chan *DecryptionShare` protocol *B* terminates correctly which also implies that everything is read correctly from channels (e.i. no thread is left blocked). I was hoping to avoid this though as I already have numerous channels in play.

Does anyone have any ideas on why this panic occurs?

EDIT:
Here's a minimal working example that doesn't produce the error though. Hopefully it can gain some insights. `*DecryptionShare` is replaced by `int`.

```
package tpsi

import (
    "math/big"
    "fmt"
    "crypto/rand"
    "testing"
)

type DecryptionShare struct {
    index int
    p *big.Int
}

func TestErs(t *testing.T) {
    message_channel1 := make(chan interface{})
    message_channel2 := make(chan []*big.Int)
    return_channel := make(chan *big.Int)
    n := 4
    go CentralParty(n, message_channel2, message_channel1, return_channel)
    for i := 1; i < n; i += 1 {
        go OtherParty(message_channel1, message_channel2, return_channel)
    }

    for i := 0; i < n; i += 1 {
        fmt.Println(<-return_channel)
    }
    t.Error("for display")
}

func CentralParty(n int, sender_channel chan<- []*big.Int, reciever_channel <-chan interface{}, return_channel chan<- *big.Int) {
    p, err := rand.Prime(rand.Reader, 256)
    if err != nil {panic(err)}

    all_p := make([]*big.Int, n)
    all_p[0] = p

    for i := 1; i < n; i += 1 {
        all_p[i] = (<-reciever_channel).(*big.Int)
    }

    for i := 1; i < n; i += 1 {
        sender_channel <- all_p
    }

    shares := make([]*DecryptionShare, 4)
    for i := 1; i < n; i += 1 {
        shares[i] = (<-reciever_channel).(*DecryptionShare)
    }

    return_channel <- shares[1].p

}

func OtherParty(sender_channel chan<- interface{}, reciever_channel <-chan []*big.Int, return_channel chan<- *big.Int) {
    p, err := rand.Prime(rand.Reader, 256)
    if err != nil {panic(err)}
    
    sender_channel <- p

    all_p := <-reciever_channel

    var ds DecryptionShare
    ds.p = p
    ds.index = all_p[0].BitLen()
    sender_channel <- &ds

    return_channel <- p

}
```

Comment: Try to rewrite your code as MWE - chances are, you will spot the bug in the process. And if not, code makes for a much better question than verbal description.

Comment: The text description is too abstract without code to allow a reader to understand what is going on, besides the fact that there is a concurrency bug somewhere. I saw you added some code, but since it doesn't reproduce the error, it is not actionable. Maybe an approach to troubleshoot is to draw a sequence diagram, this might help you shed some light and see the problem. Also, I would reconsider using separate channels instead of multiplexing, since with separate channels you say you don't have the bug and semantically they would be clearer.

Comment: @mh-cbon synchronization is achieved at the channel writes and reads. a thread *pn* blocks at step 3 until *p1* has received an passed all output from step 1. or at least that what i expect to happen.

Comment: "Here's a minimal working example that doesn't produce the error though" - then it's not going to be helpful; whatever *is* causing the bug is going to be some difference between what we can see and what your code actually looks like.

Comment: @Adrian i'm not sure what you wish to accomplish with this statement. my original question didn't contain a mwe for that exact reason but as oakad commented they thought code could ease understanding. if you doesn't agree on that, that's fine by me. but what's your proposition, should i delete it again? that's certainly not helpful. just ignore it if it isn't useful to you.

Comment: The point is, this question isn't answerable without actually demonstrating the problem. The problem is somewhere in the code you haven't shown. Until you show it, no one will be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the joint pressure of several commenters I forced myself to obtain a MWE. And as suggested by @oakad, I found the bug while doing so.

The error was (unsurprisingly) from protocol *B* which reused the `chan interface{}` once again sending the first data type `*big.Int`, and thereby introducing a race condition.

I completely neglected to consider race conditions across protocols.

Thank you for the comments!